# Emphasize the word "Google" without using their logo

Tags: search, search-results, google

[image: Google logo on webpage, created with span tags and CSS colours from ColorZilla]

I've requested permission from Google to use the above presentation. I suspect they'll say no, since they generally don't allow use of the logo. It's a two-week wait, so in the meantime, what's an elegant (and legal) way to emphasise the word Google in the above image? (By the way, both bold sentences are one label that, when clicked, move the cursor to the text box. The red star means mandatory. The logo was created with `span` tags and CSS colours grabbed from the Google logo with ColorZilla.)

According to this: https://www.google.com/permissions/trademark/rules.html I can't even use the possessive. So it seems it has to be "Google search results" not "Google's search results".

Also, should probably say "Google and Bing search results." Tried adding a Bing but there isn't one.

Update: Permission denied. "If you would like to refer to Google in plain text you are certainly free to do so."

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it isn't related to user experience or usability. Feels more like a legal/copyright concern.

Comment: @nmit026 WTF, just make the string bold. That's more than enough.

Comment: @ShreyasTripathy It's more about emphasizing page elements and directing the user's attention. The Google logo in the screenshot jumps out hugely on a page that is mostly black, white, and grey. You can't miss it, and that's what I want. If the word Google were the same as the surrounding text, some users would miss it. Sadly many users do not read every bit of text on the page, even when it's a bold heading.

Comment: @KristiyanLukanov Maybe, see my comment to Shreyas.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*I can't see your example, so this is a blind answer.*

You could simply make the text their shade of blue, which is part of their logo, used in the majority of their buttons and interface elements, plus hyperlinks are colored blue by default.

And using a similar font for your text can also help tie the link. I wouldn't do this for 1 word or sentence, but if you have several slides of your presentation about Google, you could look at a Geometric Sans like Century Gothic. Or perhaps use one of Google's own free fonts like Roboto.

Comment: Thanks, clean and simple. What colour/s do you associate with Bing? They don't seem to have a consistent logo/colour as far as I can tell.

Comment: @ nmit026 I would say yellow, but apparently they changed the logo to be teal colored a year ago. They do seem to be using that quite consistently since the introduction, though perhaps not quite as integrated in all aspects of the UI as google does.